# How to remotely deploy Docker services on an existing Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, docker-machine

I've got a `docker-compose.yml` file which defines 3 services: MySQL db, ASP.NET Core api application and Angular application. The last two images are built locally, not pulled from a remote repository. How am I supposed to log in from my local machine to Digital Ocean droplet and push my services on it?

I tried

```
docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token=myToken --digitalocean-ssh-key-path myPath  --digitalocean-ssh-user "root" dropletName
```

But it only creates a droplet. I don't want to create it because it is already created.

What's the algorithm to attach my local bash to the DO droplet's console and run `docker-compose up`? Or maybe I misunderstand the deployment procedure with Docker, what does it look like then?

Comment: Um, you ssh to it and run docker-compose directly?

Comment: Yes, I want to ssh and run. I thought that must be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use **generic** machine driver. 
From [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/):

> if you would like to import an **existing host** to allow Docker Machine
>   to manage

Use command:

```
docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address 111.111.111.111 --generic-ssh-key c:/ssh/digital-ocean droplet_name
```

In case of existing host the `create` command only creates a folder on your local machine (where Docker Client is run) with some files describing a connection.

### Possible problem

In my case I used Git Bash to connect to remote host with the command above. It seemed not working because it freezes on the line

> Waiting for SSH to be available...

and then (in the best case) it completes with:

> Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting
>   for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60)
>   exceeded

The "solution" to this was not obvious. I opened another bash window and checked whether the machine was created.

```
docker-machine ls
```

And it really was. Now I was able to activate it in my Docker Client with

```
docker-machine env machineName
```